# Buffering on audio source

Tags: javascript, audio

i'm using the Javascript for a radio player, so, sometimes someone got a bad network and the connection drops out, i want to know if there's a function like buffering, for reload the stream if it crashes.
I hope that someone could answer, thanks.

Greetings,
Julia.

Comment: Use buffered property of html audio

Comment: I didn't find that, i've searched for the audio tag params but nothing...
Can you show me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

if your use case is a radio the data is streaming so you can't access past data, if the use case is just a media-player you can use the `buffered` property of the audio element to query which is the range of the media that has been buffered at the moment or the `currentTime` property to access the current execution time.

```
var myAudioElement = document.createElementbyTag('audio')
// let's suppose that the audio element has a radio streaming attached as source 
myAudioElement.buffered // returns the last data that has been downloaded from the source
myAudioElement.currentTime // returns the time of the last data played
```

Maybe you should see something like the [connection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Connection) to be aware of when your user go offline